# C# Changing color on label doesnt work in my stacklayout

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

i am using code behind visual state managers to give selected labels a background color, but this doesnt work, any idea why?

```
      var frameStackLayoutX = new StackLayout
                {
                    Spacing = 5
                };

                var vsg = new VisualStateGroup() { Name = "CommonStates" };
                var vs = new VisualState { Name = "Selected" };

                vs.Setters.Add(new Setter
                {
                    TargetName = "Selected",
                    Property = Label.BackgroundColorProperty,
                    Value = Colors.Red
                });

                vsg.States.Add(vs);

                VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(frameStackLayoutX).Add(vsg);

                var LabelName = new Label();
                LabelName.Text = "Jhon Doe"
                LabelName .WidthRequest = 100;
                LabelName .Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
                frameStackLayoutX.Add(LabelName );

                return frameStackLayoutX;
```

This is inside a grid, wherei use `_lines.SelectedItem = pressedItem;` to make sure that I can click on my label.

Comment: you are using `Entry.BackgroundColorProperty` with a **Label**

Comment: whoops changed it to: ```Property = Label.BackgroundColorProperty,``` but it still doesnt work unfortunately. When I click on the label, it still is grey @Jason   Thanks for the reply btw!!!

Comment: how are you "selecting" the label?  Where is the code that does that?

Comment: @Jason that is inside a grid, in that grid lies the above code. I also use the following line: ```_lines.SelectedItem = pressedItem;``` to make items pressable where pressedItem is the above label

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  AFAIK you need to use `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` to set the Label's state